# how to make an abstract class or interface handle different data types

Tags: java, rgb

I am writing a program in Java that has a class object (device) that contains another object (control) and that contains another object  (controlType)

the problem I am having is each "controlType" is different.

one might be an on/off switch which can get and set a boolean but another might be a color picker which can get and set 3 bytes of RGB data.

I thought about using an abstract "controlTypeAbstract" class but I don't know how to do that with different data types.

is there a better way?

```
public abstract class controlTypeAstract {

    public abstract UnknownVariableType getData(){

    }

    public abstract void setData(UnknownVariableType data){

    }
}


public class onOffSwitch extends controlTypeAstract {
    Boolean isOn = false;

    public boolean getData(){
        return isOn;        
    }

    public void setData(Boolean data){
        isOn = data;
    }
}

public class colorControl extends controlTypeAstract {
    int redValue = 0;
    int greenValue = 0;
    int blueValue = 0;

    public int[] getData(){
        int data[];
        return (new int[] {redValue, greenValue, blueValue});       
    }

    public void setData(int[] data){
        redValue = data[0];
        greenValue = data[1];
        blueValue = data[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: [Java Generics Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: Please add some code samples.

Comment: Generics might be the answer i am reading about them now.

Comment: @user052211, please also add examples of how you want your classes to be used. API is often driven by usage examples. How the user of your classes is supposed to deal with the fact that data might be of different type? How would it look in the _calle'rs_ code? It might be imaginable "in the ideal world" example rather than something you know how to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To give a better answer it would be useful to at least see what you have implemented/tried.

From what I understand I would indeed have a control type abstract class, which handles as much common functionality as there is between controlTypes. Then each individual different controlType extends the abstract parent class. If you want to declare abstract methods in the parent class then have them just take object as a parameter, then handle that object specifically in each individual controlType as it is expected in that context.

Sorry if I entirely missed the point of your question...

Comment: sorry i am having a hard time explaining but your reply is close but as i understand it i cant pass a primitive as an object. i have added code to try and get my point across better. My problem is with what i called UnknownVariableType. at the time of the abstract class i dont know what type of data will be passed.   i might need something other then an abstract class but i dont know what that might be.